# Possible to install a 1 GB game into external storage, how?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, installation, insufficient-memory

I am using Android 6.0 marshmallow. I have 8 GB internal memory and 64 GB external memory (storage). Now I got a game from a friend which needs 1 GB of storage and I have only 400 MB as internal memory remaining. The file and directory I got from him is as -

a. game2.apk 24 MB

b. com.gamecompany.game2 (folder) 800 MB .

When I open the folder/directory I have another compressed file saying main.xx.com.gamecompany.game.obb which seems to mean it needs to go to either the data sub-directory or the /obb sub-directory, don't know which.

Now how do I install it so that the game is installed and it takes all the files it needs from the external storage. If possible I would like the game to be installed in the external storage there and it should be able to find the game files from external storage by itself. I do not know if it is possible.

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: The folder name does not indicate where to put it. Ask the person you got the data from where it has been copied from.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for no instructions,
• Android folder is on internal SD Card
( `/sdcard / android / obb`)
• Game data stays inside folder (not renamed)
• Install but don't open apk until data is copied !

[Instructions For OBB](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZNUmuZF2Yx1dlfaBbxkqsCO6PbDfIa4oVV)

Comment: I have added/edited the question bit more, maybe that gives a bit more clarity.  I'm looking for more instructions than you have shared atm or even more insight into how the internal order works so as to know what to do next.

Comment: fixed answer for the instructions to use obb

Comment: I still have a query. So should the .apk should be installed inside gamedata folder/directory or should it be installed outside or it doesn't matter ? I looked at the OBB instructions .mp4 and do thank you for the effort.